# How to use a Java Image Processing Lookup Table to replace just a single color in a Buffered Image

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics2d, java-2d

I am writing a video game and I am looking for a very fast way to recolor an Image.  The Image is currently in Black, and I would like to recolor the entire Image in red.

Could someone point me in the direction of how to use the Java Image Processing Library LookupTables on how to replace just a single color?  I am having difficulty finding an example on how to do this.
It appears that these filters you would write should be faster than having to interate through each pixel.  Is this correct?

If could provide example code on how to replace a single color with another (i.e. replace Black with Red) using the LookupTable, that would be great!

Thanks.

Here is some code from the JavaDocs for Java SE 6.  How do you write createImage?

```java
Image src = getImage("doc:///demo/images/duke/T1.gif");
ImageFilter colorfilter = new RedBlueSwapFilter();
Image img = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(src.getSource(),
                        colorfilter)); // <--- How do you write this?
```

And this is the code from JavaDocs SE 6 for `RedBlueSwapFilter`.  I assume I just can substitute Black and Red Hex codes for Red and Blue?  (i.e. I want to replace Black with Red)

```java
class RedBlueSwapFilter extends RGBImageFilter {
    public RedBlueSwapFilter() {
        // The filter's operation does not depend on the
        // pixel's location, so IndexColorModels can be
        // filtered directly.
        canFilterIndexColorModel = true;
    }

    public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
        return ((rgb & 0xff00ff00)
                | ((rgb & 0xff0000) >> 16)
                | ((rgb & 0xff) << 16));
    }
}
```

Appreciate help with this!  Thanks!

Comment: Please post *some* code. This is very vague and sounds like you want someone to hand over code.

Comment: Ok, I just posted some code I've been studying.  Confused about how to write "createImage."  Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Ok, I just posted some code I've been studying. Confused about how to write "createImage." Thanks

Comment: Did you forget about: [`java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ImageProducer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage%28java.awt.image.ImageProducer%29)?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes, I was missing that.  I spotted that shortly after I had posted this.  Would be interested why Sun/Oracle neglected to include the call to getDefaultToolkit() in their sample code?  Have never used getDefaultToolkit() before.  What is the purpose of this?  Thanks for responding!  Appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a completely red image (and it does not matter what color it was before), then there is a much simpler and faster way:

```
BufferedImage image = ... // your existing image
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
g.setPaint(Color.RED);
g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
g.dispose();
```

If you need to replace only the black pixels with red pixels, then you can use RGBImageFilter like this:

```
public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
    if(rgb == 0xff000000) { // if it was pure black
        return 0xffff0000; // change it to red 
    } else {
        return rgb; // else return as it was
    }
}
```